# Jquery Ajax call does not call Asp.net mvc controller action method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two drop-downs State and City.According to State selected city should be loaded.So I use State drop-down change event to call ajax method to populate City drop-down.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, Model.States, "Please select a State", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cities</label>

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityRegisterScreen, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Name"), "Please select a city", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**
This Contains Jquery and Javascript Code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#State").on("change", function () {  // whenever a selection is made
            $("#CityRegisterScreen").empty();

            var id = $("#State").val();


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', // we are calling json method
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCitiesByDistrict", "Account")',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (cities) {

                    $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                        $("#CityRegisterScreen").append('<option value="' + city.value + '">' +
                            city.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve cities.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

**Controller**
This is the controller action method which returns Json

```
 public JsonResult GetCitiesByDistrict(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var city = new List<City>();

        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            city = context.Cities.Where(e => e.DistrictId == id).ToList();
        }

        return Json(new SelectList(city, "Id", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Issue is when ajax method is called it doesn't call the Action method in controller.I double checked the URL and DataType it's all perfect.But Action method didn't get called.

Comment: can you manually enter that URL in a new tab and see what happens? Do you still get the issue ?

Comment: If i manually enter the URL it doesn't show the json result. instead it goes to login page..

Comment: So that means the request is not authenticated. I think that's the same issue with your Ajax call too... does your application require authorization ?

Comment: Authentication timing out? If so, use the config to increase the time, also check the response in the request to redirect to login page. Also use Postman passing in the credentials to navigate to that URL.

Comment: I am using this when registering a user..so actually user no need to login while registering..

Comment: @AslamJiffry If it shows the login page while you are entering the page URL, IT MEANS its expecting authorization. Use [AllowAnnonymous] in the method you are calling

Comment: Only use [AllowAnnonymous] if you don't need that page securing, adding for testing is fine.

Comment: Thank @Narendran pandian . after i posted my answer saw your comment.Thanks .. exactly that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

It is silly!!! How did i miss this. Thank You   @Rajshekar Reddy for your comment it guided me. I am missing `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetCitiesByDistrict(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var city = new List<City>();

        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            city = context.Cities.Where(e => e.DistrictId == id).ToList();
        }

        return Json(new SelectList(city, "Id", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Sending back a `SelectList` is just degrading your performance - create an anonymous object with the 2 properties you need. And suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - using `new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Name")` means the dropdown will not be correctly populated if you need to return the view because `ModelState` in invalid, of if your editing existing data.

Comment: I wasted well over 3 hours in order to determine that I had to remove  `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to get .post to fire

Answer (score 0):

This is a code for loading States according to selected country. Try this solution.

HTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustAddr_Country_ID, Model.Countries, "Select Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "disableInput", @id = "ddlstate", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustAddr_State_ID, ViewBag.CustAddr_State_ID as SelectList, "Select State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "disableInput"})
```

Script

```
function GetCity(_stateId) {
$("#CustAddr_State_ID").empty().trigger('change');
var newOption = new Option("Select State", 0, true, true);
$("#CustAddr_State_ID").append(newOption).trigger('change');

if (_stateId != null && _stateId != "") {
    var url = "/Ajax/GetCityByStaeId/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { stateid: _stateId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                var newOption = new Option(data[x].Text, data[x].Value, true, true);
                $("#CustAddr_State_ID").append(newOption).trigger('change');
            }
            $('#CustAddr_State_ID').val('0').trigger('change');

        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            //alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCityByStaeId(int stateid)
    {
        List<State> objcity = new List<State>();
        objcity = _state.GetState().Where(m => m.State_Country_ID == stateid).ToList();
        SelectList obgcity = new SelectList(objcity, "State_ID", "State_Name", 0);
        return Json(obgcity);
    }
```